# Why can't my UITableView load the detailView? - loadView and viewDidLoad are not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, detailview

I have a question pertaining to why my UITableView won't load a detailView...
I've done it before with an interface builder, but now I'm just trying to do it programatically, purely.

In my tableView.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController *searchDetailViewController;
```

In my tableView.m:

```
@synthesize searchDetailViewController = _searchDetailViewController;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (!self.searchDetailViewController) 
    {

        self.searchDetailViewController = [[RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];

    }

    SearchItem *item = [ content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.searchDetailViewController animated:YES];

    self.searchDetailViewController.detailItem = item;

}
```

By the way, I'd tried the initWithNibName: value to be nil, empty string as above, and even @"RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController". Nothing works...

in my RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController.h:

```
@interface RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController : UIViewController
{

    SearchItem *detailItem;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@end
```

in my RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController.m:

```
@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;

- (void)setDetailItem:(SearchItem*)newDetailItem
{
    NSLog( @"GETS HERE" );
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) 
    {

       NSLog( @"GETS HERE" );

    }

}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.

    NSLog( @"DOES NOT GET HERE" );

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog( @"DOES NOT GET HERE" );
}
```

As seen above, when I'd implemented a few debugging prints... It does what it's supposed to in theory but for some reason does not load the views. This manifests itself in the GUI by nothing happening when a table cell is clicked, when the view should change into the subview.

What am I doing wrong? Please help... It's been driving me crazy, and I'd been rummaging through the interweb for a while now in hopes of answers.

Thanks a bunch - I really appreciate it! ;)

Sincerely,
Piotr.

Comment: your didselectedrowatindexpath method call?

Comment: If u r doing it programmatically purely, then first check if ur `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is getting called or not? If it is not getting called then `Your_tableView.delegate = self;` & `Your_tableView.datasource = self;`
I am not being sarcastic but this is the most common forget done by programmer when he shifts from IB to pure programming.

Comment: Log self.navigationcontroller when you are pushing the detail view. If that is nil, it will produce the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: YESSIR! NSLog( @"NAV: %@", self.navigationController); produces: NAV: (null). What can I do? Looks like it's close to being resolved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a nib, change this line of code:

```
self.searchDetailViewController = [[RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
```

To

```
self.searchDetailViewController = [[RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController alloc] init];
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi skram, thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately, it's still the same. I was thinking it might be something to do with the nib, but not sure how to go about it...

Comment: No problem, You initially sated you weren't using interface builder which is it?

Comment: Have you created your RLCASearchDetailViewControllerViewController using IB or programmatically?

Comment: Nuzhat Zari, I've created it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view is not embedded in a navigation controller, so it can't push a new view controller.

Since the detail view controller is never displayed on the screen, it never bothers loading its view, which is why you are seeing nothing from your loadView or viewDidLoad methods.

You don't show how you set up the initial view controller for your app, but it should be a navigation controller, with your table view controller as the root view controller.

If you're a beginner, storyboards are much better to use than trying to do it all in code. There are few benefits and lots of drawbacks to avoiding interface builder.

Comment: Hmmm... Right now I'm confused as to how I should do that to be honest... I do searchNavController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:searchMasterViewController];  but that's a different UIViewController from the table view entirely... Although searchMasterViewController is where the table view is called from.

Comment: How do you put your table view on the screen in the first place?

Comment: I add the self.tableView where self is the table view controller to the parent the view of a UIViewController as a subview.